# Existence of a resource within a resource group

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli, express-router

How to check the existence of a express route within a resource group. I have list of resource group but not all resource groups have express routes within them. What is the condition that needs to be written to check if there is a express route inside each resource group

rgList ==> List of all the resource groups in a specific subscription

erList ==> List of all the express routes in a specific subscription

```
rgList="$(az group list --subscription "sub1" --query [].name --output tsv)"
erList="$(az network express-route list --subscription "sub1" --query [].name --output tsv)"
for i in $rgList; do
    if [[ $(az network express-route list -g "$i" --subscription "sub-network-central-services" --query "[].name | length(@))" > 0 ]]
    then
        for j in $erList; do
            hubname+="$(az network express-route auth list --circuit-name "$j" --resource-group "$i" --query [].authorizations[].name --output tsv)"
        done
    fi
done
```

I am getting the below error
**bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, yes there were some syntactical errors while testing in our local environment we have fixed those errors & we have modified the above script as well.

The Modified script will pull the authorization names & Express-route circuit name.

If want to get the ***list of resource groups which has express-route circuit*** you can directly refer to ***Alternative Script*** in the My solution.

**Here is the Modified Bash Script:**

```html
hubname=""
rglist=$(az group list --subscription "<subNameorSubId>" --query [].name --output tsv)
erList=$(az network express-route list --subscription "<subNameorSubId>" --query [].name --output tsv)
for i in $rglist;
do
if [[ $(az network express-route list -g $i --subscription "<subNameorSubId>" --query "[].name | length(@)") > 0 ]]
    then
        for j in $erList;
        do
             hubname+=$(az network express-route auth list --circuit-name $j --resource-group $i --query [].name --output tsv)
             echo $j,$hubname
        done
    fi
done
```

**Here is the sample output screenshot for reference:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the below bash script this will give you the list of resource groups if an express-route circuit is present in it.

**Alternative Script:**

```html
 rgList=$(az group list --subscription "<SubNameorSubId>" --query [].name --output tsv)
    for i in $rgList;do
        resourcelist=$(az resource list -g $i --query [].type -o tsv)
        for j in $resourcelist;do
            if [[ $j ==  "Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits" ]]
            then
                echo $i
            fi
        done
    done
```

**Here is the Sample Output for reference:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution it works. But i am getting error when the express route circuit is not available in the first resource group. Is there any way to ignore the error and then increment the j value so that it displays only the available circuits with the correct resource group name @VenkateshDodda-MT

Comment: ERROR: (ResourceNotFound) The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits/er01' under resource group 'rg01' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
Code: ResourceNotFound

How to ignore this error and check if er02 is there in rg01